# How to integrate Azure Application Insights with ABP Framework

Tags: abp

ABP Framework Version :- 7.1.1

Trying to integrate Azure Application Insights

we are seeing below message

AI: Diagnostic message: Performance counters are unavailable when the application is running under IIS Express. Use EnableIISExpressPerformanceCounters element with a value of 'true' within the Performance Collector Module element to override this behavior.

is there anything we are missing program.cs

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.WriteTo.Async(c => c.File("Logs/logs.txt"))
.WriteTo.Async(c => c.Console())
.CreateLogger();
```

We followed the below article but not able to log anything in Azure Application Insights
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-azure-application-insights-for-exception-logging-in-c-sharp/